# Get redirected URL from an image redirect in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Imagine we have an img tag which points to http://example.com/photo.png.  This call results in a 302 redirect to http://example.com/path/to/my/photo.png.  Is there a way from javascript that I can see the second address, the one to which the image was redirected?  I'm assuming that such a thing is not possible, but would love to know if it is.

**Update:** Please note that I am talking about an IMG tag.  All of the responses are assuming that I am using an ajax request.  Clearly, as you can tell above, that is not the case.

Comment: If an image's src is pointed to a URL that responds 304, redirect should happen automatically (in modern brosers). You can, however, see all response headers too if you needed to.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm interested in accessing, the response headers of the image request.  How do I do that?

Comment: Here is the specification documentation http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getallresponseheaders()-method and there should be wrapper methods in different JS libs.

Comment: Please note, once again, that I am dealing with an IMAGE request.  In other words, I have <img src="...">.  I never instantiate XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying too. Example: I have a RewriteRule that redirects requests to images accessed by `/uploads/...`. For every such image during a page load, I get two requests logged by Firebug. `http://192.168.160.129/uploads/section/220/5baff22fb1322fa6201a8de6a22d470c1dc7feb5.jpg` and `http://192.168.160.129/media@section/220/5baff22fb1322fa6201a8de6a22d470c1dc7feb5.jpg` The original request is made by the browser because the first URL is defined as an image's `src`.

Comment: But how do I get that second URL?  I have no XMLHttpRequest instance because it was created as part of an image element.

Comment: Then you will have to create one and use an async request to the first URL (and then get the value of the "Location" header), because otherwise I don't think there's a way to get this out from the Image object since it's src attribute doesn't change.